# Making viewing of cookies neat n tidy

Tags: javascript, cookies

If I go to a website, open the console and type:

```
document.cookie.split(";")
["__atuvc=1%7C36", " openid_provider=facebook", " splitVar=Get Alerts!", " _ga=GA1.2.517247621.1408458879"]
```

I get all of the cookies back. I saw once a while ago someone showing me something in a different program (I think it was mongoDB) where they applied a .pretty method that would do this to the above:

```
__atuvc=1%7C36", 
"openid_provider=facebook",
"splitVar=Get Alerts!",
"ga=GA1.2.517247621.1408451239"
```

Does such a method exist? It would just let me see with ease and convenience, the cookies on a website.

Put another way is there a way to neatly view name value pairs (Is a cookie an object?) on separate lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.cookie.replace(/;/g,',\n')`

If you want to please your eyes with some space, you could add that:

`document.cookie.replace(/;/g,',\n').replace(/=/g,'\t=\t');`

Here, the first parameter of the `.replace()` method is a regular expression (Regex).

The 'g' is an option that says to replace multiple occurences of the expression instead of just the first one.
In the first example, `,\n` is a colon followed by a line break, replacing every semi colon. In the second one, we insert tabs around the `=` sign.

Comment: That works but why? Why is the semi colon enclosed in slashes and not just single quotes? What is 'g'? What is 'n'?

Comment: @DougFirr, those are regexes (regular expressions). You should get familiar with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily turn the string `document.cookie` returns into an object, which will be readable enough in any console.

```
var cookies = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie).split(";"), res = {};
cookies.forEach(function(cookie){
    var parts = cookie.split("=");
    res[parts[0]] = parts[1];
});
console.log(res);
```